# Cannot import framework file in custom framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am creating a custom framework in iOS. I have a built-in framework as shown in the image. When I try to import a file from an already created framework (`Ex,smma`) I get the error `"smma.h" file not found`. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to include it in your umbrella header file? If your project needs to use your custom framework and the framework that your custom framework is referencing, you should add them both to the project.

Comment: @JDx i want hide my framework (smma). other developer they can only import custom framework but internally it will work my framework. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues with creating my own framework and including it in a project. I found Kodmunki had a really useful guide.

https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/ios-9-universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks/

Pay particular attention to the section on Adding Frameworks to an App. This was where I was making mistakes. Once I followed the steps in this section I found it was working correctly.

Comment: @AvijitNagare the import line doesn't look correct to me the path looks too long try:  #import<smma/smma.h>